# Dropdown Field Error - Gravity Forms

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have created a calculating form using Gravity Forms plugin for Wordpress.

I have a dropdown menu in my form. The problem is, that the various drop down "labels" are not displaying with the relevant selections made.

My dropdown menu is setup as follows:

> 1. Apples and Oranges |  50
> 2. Oranges and Lemons |  50
> 3. Pineapples         |  50
> 4. tomatoes           |  80

So, whether the user selects option 1, 2, or 3 - the label "Apples and oranges" appears. 
The only time that the label changes, is if the user selects an option with a different value.

It seems that the plugin is only displaying a different option if the value changes, and it sees every option with the value of "50" as the same option.

I hope I am explaining myself correctly.

Thank you

Comment: A link to a working examples or some screenshots/code will probably be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the submit GF will go through the menu options and show the option which will have the selected value.
So the behavior is perfectly normal, the first one with a value 50 is set as selected.

You will have to use different values for each menu item and with code you'll need to determine the price of each menu.
In your program you would need a table like:

```
1 - 50
2 - 50
3 - 50
4 - 80
```

Your drop down will be

```
Apples and Oranges | 1
Oranges and Lemons | 2
Pineapples | 3
tomatoes | 4
```

You can also be creative and go with something like

```
Apples and Oranges | 50-1
Oranges and Lemons | 50-2
Pineapples | 50-3
tomatoes | 80-1
```

And then strip the -* from the value for calculations.

Comment: @Peter van der Does - Thank you  kindly for your reply.  I now understand how I can go about this.  How can I strip the -* from the value for calculations? would this need to be done in the "backend" of the plugin?

Comment: Yes, whatever you do with the form. I'm assuming you store the info in a database, so replacing the value there would be an option.